i got data from a form using the post method and i want to pass that value to another page using but it is not working. Redirect a POST to a GET
please help me correct this code
$salt = 'XyZzy12*_';
$stored_hash = '1a52e17fa899cf40fb04cfc42e6352f1';
//$stored_hash = 'a8609e8d62c043243c4e201cbb342862';  // Pw is meow123
$salted = md5($salt);
$failure = false;  // If we have no POST data

// Check to see if we have some POST data, if we do process it
if ( isset($_POST['who']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {
    if ( strlen($_POST['who']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
        $failure = "User name and password are required";
        
    } else {
        $check = hash('md5', $salted.$_POST['pass']);
        //print "$check";
        if ( $check == $stored_hash ) {
            // Redirect the browser to game.php
            header("Location: game.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['who']) );
            return ;
        } else {
            $failure = "Incorrect password";
        }
    }
}

The first stored_hash is not working and when i put the second an error occur saying expected a POST to redirect to a GET but received POST
I tried passing the just the page game.php but it is still not working and when i look the code from my research it seems currect

Putting aside the problem of using MD5 for password hashing [use pasword_hash()], your entire login system is defeated if I just type game.php?name=admin in the address bar. Use session data.

$salted.$_POST['pass'] would be 4b42201ceb7acca0295fdb0d8b7cac8ameow123 then, and the md5 of that is b82fec8f9b1ac5cb74cdefeb6baed173. Not equal to either of the $stored_hash values you got there.

"and when i put the second an error occur saying expected a POST to redirect to a GET but received POST" - where does that error come from? Can you expand on "not working" and "still not working"?

And post the exact error message, not abbreviated or paraphrased please, and tell us which line threw it. Then we know precisely what is happening

Warning: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong (some of which this code has already taken advantage of!). It's not a good task for an inexperienced programmer. Modern dev frameworks like Laravel comes with an authentication system built-in. I recommend focusing your time learning PHP and adding real value to your app with new features, not something you can re-use a (reliable, well-made) product for

The $salted variable contains the MD5 hash of the salt, which doesn't seem correct. Instead, you should concatenate the salt directly with the password and then hash it.
Also it seems like you are using hasg incorrectly, for md5 you can use md5() instead of hash('md5', ...).
From my view, it seems that the given hashes do not appear to match
I would suggest something like this:
$salt = 'XyZzy12*_';
$stored_hash = ''; // TODO: Input your stored hash here..
$failure = false;  // If there should be no POST data

// If there is POST data, process it
if (isset($_POST['who']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['who']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1) {
        $failure = "User name and password are required";
    } else {
        // Correctly concatenate the salt and password, then hash
        $check = md5($salt . $_POST['pass']);
        if ($check == $stored_hash) {
            // Redirect the browser to game.php
            header("Location: game.php?name=" . urlencode($_POST['who']));
            exit; // Use exit after header to prevent further code execution
        } else {
            $failure = "Incorrect password";
        }
    }
}

